# php how to replace multi first | and last | to other character in string

Tags: php, replace

Example I have: `Today is | nice day | go to | school now | and enjoy | your life |.`

I tried:

```
$text = str_replace('| ','"',$text);
$text = str_replace(' |','"',$text);
```

Result is:

```
Today is "nice day "go to "school now "and enjoy "your life ".
```

you can see result bad -> `...day "go` ; `...now "and` ; `...life ".`

Result should be: `Today is "nice day" go to "school now" and enjoy "your life".`

I have many text like this to replace, please help!

Comment: I don’t understand how `school | now | and` becomes `"school now" and`

Comment: sorry my bad typing, it's | school now | bro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, using a regular expression to replace matches.  In this case, we also capture the text between two | markers and use the captured text in the replacement:

```
$text = "Today is | nice day | go to | school now | and enjoy | your life |.";
echo $text; echo "\r\n\r\n";

$text = preg_replace("~\| (.*?) \|~", '"$1"', $text);
echo $text; echo "\r\n\r\n";
```

See this fiddle:

https://ideone.com/Zlij00

Comment: sorry my bad typing, it's | school now | bro, result should be "school now"

Comment: Yes, so the solution works, correct?

Comment: See this fiddle: https://ideone.com/Zlij00

Comment: Great, glad to hear it.  :) If you're not familiar with regular expressions you should look into them.  They are extremely useful in text manipulation and pattern matching.